# Problem with ros networking

Tags: ros, network, remote-launch, remote-roscore, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Desktop Pc and a Remote pc on a pioneer base as my Ros fuerte architecture. On this one I ran my roscore and some nodes to interact with the pioneer. The rest nodes I run them on the PC. I am having a problem with the network. When I launch a launch file from ros with the machine tag from the Desktop computer to the laptop on the pioneer.

as explained here: ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/machine

I get an error:

remote[higgs-0]: failed to launch on higgs:
Unable to establish ssh connection to [higgs:22]: No authentication methods available

But I am able to connect each machines using the ssh command bidirectionally.
I use the ROS variables ROS_HOSTNAME(name of each machine) ROS_MASTER_URI(higgs_ip). You can rostopic echo from the different machines, or see the rviz on the Desktop computer from the information on the sensor on the pioneer base. But I have to launch the nodes on the laptop directly.

I will appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57892/problem-with-ros-networking/) by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on 2013-04-11**:
Thank you for your help tbh.

I have set the sshkeys correctly, I do not have to enter the password anymore. But I am still experiencing the same error.

remote[higgs-0]: failed to launch on higgs: Unable to establish ssh connection to [higgs:22]: No authentication methods available

Maybe is the fact that I am using different users in each machine?

I have checked .ssh/autorized_keys in higgs (robot laptop, where I want my remote launch to execute)

ssh -rsa blablabla agonzamart@arturo-desktop (my user and computer) ssh -rsa blablabla higgs@higgs (the user I use in the robot laptop) ssh -rsa blablabla root@arturo-desktop (root user from my computer)

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you ssh to higgs, do you usually need to enter a password? If so, then you probably need to set up your sshkeys. Here's a [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) on how to do it.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on 2013-04-11**:
Thank you for your help tbh.

I have set the sshkeys correctly, I do not have to enter the password anymore. But I am still experiencing the same error.

remote[higgs-0]: failed to launch on higgs: Unable to establish ssh connection to [higgs:22]: No authentication methods available

Maybe is the fact that I am using different users in each machine?

I have checked .ssh/autorized_keys in higgs (robot laptop, where I want my remote launch to execute)

ssh -rsa blablabla agonzamart@arturo-desktop (my user and computer) ssh -rsa blablabla higgs@higgs (the user I use in the robot laptop) ssh -rsa blablabla root@arturo-desktop (root user from my computer)

I will appreciate any help.